# json with google geocoding api

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, google-geocoder

Here is code which gets latitude and longitute when entered a location.I believe that my code right according to my knowledge.but i get a blank page after entering a place.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
    var query;
    var sensor="&sensor=false";
    var callback="&callback=?";


    $("button").click(function(){
          query=$("#query").val();
          $.getJSON(url+query+sensor+callback,function(json){

             $('#results').append('<p>Latitude : ' + json.results.geometry.location.lat+ '</p>');
             $('#results').append('<p>Longitude: ' + json.results.geometry.location.lng+ '</p>');

});


    });
});


</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="query" /><button>Get Coordinates</button>
<div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use JSONP here.

> **JSONP**
>
> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request > is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.
>
> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

But the URL you're calling returns **plain** JSON, so the parsing fails with a syntax error and `getJSON` fails silently.

Now when you try to change the geocode URL to use JSONP, you get a `404` error since Google has removed support for JSONP quite a while ago:

- http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1872
- http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2009/11/jsonp-and-google-maps-api-geocoder-not.html

**In short:**
You cannot simply use the geocode api from Browser JavaScript anymore, you'll have to add a proxy script on your server.

And even if the request would work, your code still has a bug in it:

`json.results` is an **array** of results, so it has no `geometry` property.

You have to access the first element of the array in order to get to the actual object that has the `geometry` property:

```
json.results[9].geometry.location.lng
```

Comment: my request is working.I tested it with firebug.when i enter a location i get the response.I just have to parse  the jsonp and ouput it.I think so>is it rgt?

Answer (score 15):

In Google Maps Javascript V3 you can access the geocoding service using the google.maps.Geocoder class.

```
var myAddressQuery = 'O. J. Brochs g 16a, Bergen';
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
geocoder.geocode(
    { address : myAddressQuery, 
      region: 'no' 
    }, function(results, status){
      // result contains an array of hits.
});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: It is against the Terms to use without a map, however.