# Is geocoding limited by only 10 results in Google Maps JS API 3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I want to use Google Maps' geocoding service and list all locations that fit user's request. According to [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index) there are static and dynamic services. The first one is what I need but seems to me it doesn't work as I would prefer. I want to get the results as JSON but the server doesn't generate a response in JSONP compliant manner. As I found [JSONP support has been removed from the API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682673/506695).

That's why I tried to use [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_geocoder) class of dynamic API. The issue is that I receive no more than ten result items for any address request (at least I couldn't guess the address with more than ten result items). I understand that such limit is for real-time geocoding but does it mean that it is impossible to get a full list of all possible locations that fit a request using Google Maps API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing names and address. Google maps tries to be accurate as possible and returns a list of wild guesses when it doesn't find the exact match. It's up to you to find the best places that's meet your name. Geocding has nothing to do with proximity search. When you need a proximity search you need to use another api (maybe places) or do it yourself with a database with your own unique places. This holds true especially when you add the regioncode to your query. Read more about it: [Google Maps API: Geocode returns different co-ordinates then Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788664/google-maps-api-geocode-returns-different-co-ordinates-then-google-maps/12790012#12790012). Read here about a question about google places: [understand the google places api for using with a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325946/understand-the-google-places-api-for-using-with-a-webpage).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has limit for about 10 geocoding requests per second. Workaround? Delay each request with a status of `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` for about 100 milliseconds.

Comment: I mean not the requests' rate but the amount of obtained locations (addresses). So I receive no more than 10 relevant addresses. How can I request other addresses to be able to implement a pagination having 10 results per one page?